# Why should I limit the column length in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If you're sure you will not exceed the numer 9999 you should limit the column int(4).
But I was wondering:

- WHY? What is the advantage?
- And is a tinyint(4) better than an int(4)?

Thanks!

Comment: The bracketed number after the field type has nothing to do with how large of a number the field can store. An int field is always 4 bytes, and a tinyint is always 1 byte - the bracketed number is simply a hint to mysql on how many digits should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not used to `limit` anything, except when ZEROFILL is in play.

Reference: http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/